# how to implement ngrx in angular2

Tags: angular, ngrx

new to ngrx,am developing an app using angular2seedadvanced.i want to implement ngrx/store in this app. am referring

- http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/

code files are here

action.ts

```
export class HeroActions {
static LOAD_HEROES = '[Hero] Load Heroes';
loadHeroes(): Action {
    return {
        type: HeroActions.LOAD_HEROES
    };
}

static LOAD_HEROES_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Load Heroes Success';
loadHeroesSuccess(heroes): Action {
    return {
        type: HeroActions.LOAD_HEROES_SUCCESS,
        payload: heroes
    };
}
}
```

reducer.ts

```
export default function (state = initialState, action: Action): HeroListState {
switch (action.type) {
    case HeroActions.LOAD_HEROES_SUCCESS: {
        return action.payload;
    }
    case HeroActions.ADD_HERO_SUCCESS: {
        return [...state, action.payload];
    }
}
```

effect.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroEffects {
constructor (
    private update$: Actions,
    private heroActions: HeroActions,
    private svc: HeroService
) {}

@Effect() loadHeroes$ = this.update$
    .ofType(HeroActions.LOAD_HEROES)
    .switchMap(() => this.svc.getHeroes())
    .map(heroes => this.heroActions.loadHeroesSuccess(heroes));

@Effect() getHero$ = this.update$
    .ofType(HeroActions.GET_HERO)
    .map<string>(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap(id => this.svc.getHero(id))
    .map(hero => this.heroActions.getHeroSuccess(hero));
```

and in my component.ts

```
 constructor(){
  this.grocerys$ = store.select('list');// listview binding
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadItems();
    this.store.dispatch(this.heroActions.loadHeroes());
  };
```

but my list will not get updating.what all other things i need to implement? now My output is

[object Object] //    <== Problem here.
any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Have you registered the `HeroEffects` in your module with `EffectsModule.run(HeroEffects)`?

Comment: i gave it in my webmodule.ts EffectsModule.run(HeroEffects) but unfortunately nothing will be displayed in the list.

Comment: Can you expand on where that [object Object] is coming from? Also, is the load heroes success action being dispatched with correct data inside the reducer?

Comment: thanks. i fixed my problem it was on the view                                                       <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let grocery of (grocerys$ | async)">{{grocery.name}}</li>
    </ul>                                                                                                           this fixed my problem.Thanks all